# Using loops to generate a pattern

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to generate the following output pattern:

```
400 , 400
300 , 400
300 , 300
200 , 400
200 , 300
200 , 200 
100 , 400
100 , 300
100 , 200
100 , 100
0 , 400
0 , 300
0 , 200
0 , 100
0 , 0
```

This is the for loop I have implemented:

```py
for i in range(100, 500, 100):
    for j in range(100, 500, 100):
        print(i, "i", j, "j")
```

However, the generated output isn't as I want:

```
100 i 100 j
100 i 200 j
100 i 300 j
100 i 400 j
200 i 100 j
200 i 200 j
200 i 300 j
200 i 400 j
300 i 100 j
300 i 200 j
300 i 300 j
300 i 400 j
400 i 100 j
400 i 200 j
400 i 300 j
400 i 400 j
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any "gain" in trying to generate the pattern you want with a loop and ranges. Because your desired output is "**irregular**" and so cannot be meaningfully generated using loops.

To exemplify, if you haven't made any mistake in transcribing your desired output. What you state you want is this:

> `X - 400 300 300 400 300 200 100 100 100 100   0   0   0   0  0`
>
> `Y - 400 400 300 200 200 200 400 300 200 100 400 300 200 100  0`

If you look at it closely, there's no way to code this with ranges or loops **without including exceptions in almost every iteration**. So in this case what does make sense is considering the pattern as a "**constant**", and explicitly coding it as a tuple:

```py
X_pattern = (400, 300, 300, 400, 300, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100,   0,   0,   0,  0,  0)
Y_pattern = (400, 400, 300, 200, 200, 200, 400, 300, 200, 100, 400, 300, 200, 100,  0)

for x, y in zip(X_pattern, Y_pattern):
    print('{:n}, {:n}, '.format(x, y),  sep='', end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```py
start=400
step=-100
end=400


pattern=[]


while(end>step):
    end-=100
    for i in range(start, end, step):
        pattern.append([end-step, i])

print(pattern)
```